Converting opencv::DMatch feature matches into a colmap database
I am detecting features and matches using opencv, and attempting to pass the data into a colmap database for reconstruction. (I am doing it this way to use custom features and matching techniques).
I am adding the data like so:
void colmapFunctions::CreateEmptyDatabase(const std::string& database_path) {
    // create database
    colmap::Database database(database_path);

}

// Function to add keypoints to the COLMAP database
void colmapFunctions::add_keypoints_to_database(const std::string& database_path,
    const int image_id,
    const std::vector<cv::KeyPoint>& keypoints) {
    // Convert OpenCV keypoints to COLMAP's Eigen::MatrixXf format
    colmap::FeatureKeypoints colmap_keypoints = ConvertKeypointsToCOLMAP(keypoints);

    colmap::Database database(database_path);

    // Write the keypoints to the database
    database.WriteKeypoints(image_id, colmap_keypoints);

    std::cout << "Added " << keypoints.size() << " keypoints to the database for image ID " << image_id << std::endl;
}


void colmapFunctions::add_matches_to_database(const std::string& database_path,
    const int image_id1,
    const int image_id2,
    const std::vector<cv::DMatch>& matches) {
    colmap::FeatureMatches colmap_matches = ConvertMatchesToCOLMAP(matches);

    colmap::Database database(database_path);

    // Write the matches to the database
    database.WriteMatches(image_id1, image_id2,colmap_matches);

    std::cout << "Added " << colmap_matches.size() << " matches between images ID " << image_id1 << " and " << image_id2 << std::endl;
}

// Function to convert OpenCV keypoints to COLMAP keypoints
colmap::FeatureKeypoints ConvertKeypointsToCOLMAP(const std::vector<cv::KeyPoint>& keypoints) {
    colmap::FeatureKeypoints colmap_keypoints;
    colmap_keypoints.reserve(keypoints.size());

    // Convert each OpenCV keypoint to COLMAP FeatureKeypoint
    for (const auto& kp : keypoints) {
        colmap::FeatureKeypoint colmap_kp;
        colmap_kp.x = kp.pt.x;       // X-coordinate of the keypoint
        colmap_kp.y = kp.pt.y;       // Y-coordinate of the keypoint      

        // Add the converted keypoint to the vector
        colmap_keypoints.push_back(colmap_kp);
    }

    return colmap_keypoints;
}

colmap::FeatureMatches ConvertMatchesToCOLMAP(const std::vector<cv::DMatch> matches)
{
    colmap::FeatureMatches colmap_matches;

    // Convert each DMatch to COLMAP Match
    for (const auto& match : matches) {
        colmap::FeatureMatch colmap_match;    
        colmap_match.point2D_idx1 = match.queryIdx; // Index in the first image
        colmap_match.point2D_idx2 = match.trainIdx; // Index in the second image

        // Add the converted match to the vector
        colmap_matches.push_back(colmap_match);
    }

    return colmap_matches;
}

It seems to work, however when I load the database in the colmap GUI, it tells me no matches are found. What is wrong here? (I also load images and cameras, which are found correctly)
